# Lanzamiento y captura de excepciones JAVA

Tags: java, xml, datos

tengo un código que lee un XML para extraer datos y los almacena en clases. Estoy utilizando JAVA para desarrollar esto.

Hay algunos datos que son obligatorios, y por ahora lo que he hecho es imprimir un mensaje de error por pantalla cuando detecte que alguno de estos datos falta.

Ahora bien, lo que me gustaría hacer es que, en vez de imprimir el mensaje por pantalla, lanzar una excepción con un mensaje personalizado, y poder capturar dicha excepción.

Lo que tengo ahora mismo es algo asi:

```
Element contractFolderIDNode = (Element) cfs.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ContractFolderID").item(POS_UNICO_ELEMENTO);

// Compruebo la existencia del ContractFolderID, si no existe se queda a null y mandamos mensaje
if (contractFolderIDNode != null){
    this.contractFolderID = contractFolderIDNode.getTextContent();
}else{
    System.err.print("ERROR FATAL: ContractFolderStatus -> CONTRACT FOLDER ID no existe\n");
}
```

Y me gustaría algo así, pero no sé cómo hacerlo exactamente:

```
Element contractFolderIDNode = (Element) cfs.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ContractFolderID").item(POS_UNICO_ELEMENTO);

// Compruebo la existencia del ContractFolderID, si no existe se queda a null y mandamos mensaje
if (contractFolderIDNode != null){
    this.contractFolderID = contractFolderIDNode.getTextContent();
}else{
    // Lanzo una excepción, la capturo y muestro el mensaje de error por pantalla
}
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE: NO SE DEBE DETENER LA EJECUCIÓN DEL PROGRAMA SI SE DETECTA UN FALLO ASÍ** ->
Sé que se puede hacer mediante un *throw new Exception()*, pero eso detiene el programa y no quiero que pase esto.

Esto lo quiero hacer así sobre todo para cuando le haga pruebas unitarias, pues con capturas de excepciones es más fácil hacer estas pruebas.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: No. throw new Exception no detiene la ejecucion, siempre y cuando el metodo que llamo a este agarre esa excepcion... El metodo que llama a esta funcion, esta alrededor de un try catch?

Comment: En el momento en que "lanzas" una exception el programa se va a detener.FIN. Lo que puedes hacer es, capturar la excepción con un try-catch y guardarla en un fichero de texto o en Base de datos "para almacenarla" pero el throw new tuException va a detener el programa, es algo básico.